# Cannot install pyfftw3 by pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, pyfftw

I am trying using FFTW3 in python and when I try to install it I got this:

```
xxxxxxx@iMac ~ % pip3 install pyfftw3      
Collecting pyfftw3
  Using cached PyFFTW3-0.2.1.tar.gz (25 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-m021xxq5/pyfftw3_69a9370f7f41441eaca6ae508a6a1544/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-m021xxq5/pyfftw3_69a9370f7f41441eaca6ae508a6a1544/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-m06gikf1
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-m021xxq5/pyfftw3_69a9370f7f41441eaca6ae508a6a1544/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-m021xxq5/pyfftw3_69a9370f7f41441eaca6ae508a6a1544/setup.py", line 81
        print "build %s from template %s" %(outfile, tmplfile)
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/07/e070b9a44429bbd5481f9f0b2d1b35d896fbfd180051e05c840186a31c8a/PyFFTW3-0.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=8941a023e6e4f501e7cec92382c3d3f76f47c7583e9eade738840dd9e4e467c4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyfftw3/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyfftw3
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyfftw3
```

I have the newest version of python installed by Homebrew.
Pip is also the newest version.
I have tried `pip install -U setuptools`

---

Inspired by 'Swetank Poddar': I found the `pyfftw3` is a python2 library, so I tried `pip3 install pyfftw`. But, I got a new question:

```
Collecting pyfftw
  Downloading pyFFTW-0.12.0.tar.gz (137 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 137 kB 167 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyfftw) (1.19.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyfftw
  Building wheel for pyfftw (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-p3twpksg/pyfftw_a5a93b1d21cd45bb90489634e47c82a5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-p3twpksg/pyfftw_a5a93b1d21cd45bb90489634e47c82a5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-wheel-e51wsh5k
       cwd: /private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-p3twpksg/pyfftw_a5a93b1d21cd45bb90489634e47c82a5/
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw
  copying pyfftw/config.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw
  copying pyfftw/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw
  copying pyfftw/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/builders
  copying pyfftw/builders/builders.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/builders
  copying pyfftw/builders/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/builders
  copying pyfftw/builders/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/builders
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/scipy_fft.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/dask_fft.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/numpy_fft.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/scipy_fftpack.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  copying pyfftw/interfaces/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/interfaces
  UPDATING build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/_version.py
  set build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/_version.py to '0.12.0'
  running build_ext
  error: Could not find any of the FFTW libraries
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyfftw
  Running setup.py clean for pyfftw
Failed to build pyfftw
Installing collected packages: pyfftw
    Running setup.py install for pyfftw ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-p3twpksg/pyfftw_a5a93b1d21cd45bb90489634e47c82a5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-p3twpksg/pyfftw_a5a93b1d21cd45bb90489634e47c82a5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-record-ljyxfo00/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyfftw
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-p3twpksg/pyfftw_a5a93b1d21cd45bb90489634e47c82a5/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    UPDATING build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/_version.py
    set build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/pyfftw/_version.py to '0.12.0'
    running build_ext
    error: Could not find any of the FFTW libraries
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-p3twpksg/pyfftw_a5a93b1d21cd45bb90489634e47c82a5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-install-p3twpksg/pyfftw_a5a93b1d21cd45bb90489634e47c82a5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xc/vzy2gb2j2hs8tyv7j70d979h0000gn/T/pip-record-ljyxfo00/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyfftw Check the logs for full command output.
```

It looks like the problem is mainly about the "Building wheel for pyfftw".

Comment: That looks like a python2 library. Try using `pip` rather than `pip3` (assuming you have python 2  installed)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I searched `pyfftw` on [link](https://pypi.org/), it shows `pyfftw3` is a python2 library, `pyfftw` is python3 library, but I meet a new problem for installing `pyfftw`. Please have a look at my edited question.

Comment: pyfftw is a python wrapper around FFTW libraries. You need to download those libraries and update your env values (it should be mentioned in the PYFFTW docs)

Comment: Currently there are no pre-built binaries for Python 3.9, so you'll either have to build it yourself, or possibly easier would be to use, say Python 3.8, in which case the install should just work, or else you can wait until 3.9 is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could install [pyFFTW](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW): `pip install pyFFTW`

[Install instructions for Mac OS](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW#mac-osx):
Install FFTW from homebrew:

```
brew install fftw
```

Set temporary environmental variables, such that pyfftw finds fftw:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
```

Now install pyfftw from pip:

```
pip install pyfftw
```

It has been suggested that macports might also work fine. You should then replace the LD environmental variables above with the right ones.

- DYLD - path for libfftw3.dylib etc - find /usr -name libfftw3.dylib
- LDFLAGS - path for fftw3.h - find /usr -name fftw3.h

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I got a new problem when I tried to install `pyfftw`

Comment: I updated my Answer for more information visit the [GitHub repo of pyFFTW](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW)

Comment: I can't make this work in my Mac M1. error: Could not find the FFTW header 'fftw3.h'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyfftw

Comment: Have you tried [these steps](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/314)? Even though the person who reported the issue is not using apple silicone there are instructions on how to install pyfftw for M1 Macs.

Answer (score 0):

check the python version once ,by typing **python --version** and if it is the latest version of python go to the code that you are typing and check the print statement as it is showing error in command prompt as you mentioned...in latest version of python you have to use parenthesis after print("you have to use parenthesis")

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/issues/303

1. Run `brew install fftw`
2. Install the lib with `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

For MacBook Air @ M1 a mix of instructions helped me:

1. `brew install fftw`
2. Find locations of `libfftw3.dylib` and `fftw3.h` and [set environmental variables](https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW?tab=readme-ov-file#mac-osx)

   Example:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/include"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
```

3. Clone `pyFFTW` repo

   `git clone git@github.com:pyFFTW/pyFFTW.git`
4. Install `pyFFTW`

   `CFLAGS="-Wno-implicit-function-declaration" pip install -e . -v`

Links:

- https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW?tab=readme-ov-file#mac-osx
- https://github.com/andrej5elin/howto_fftw_apple_silicon